# Why $Z(A)$ is an equivalence relation on $A$?

Tags: universal-algebra

For every algebra $A$, the center $Z(A)$ is a congruence on $A$.
Why is $Z(A)$ an equivalence relation on $A$?

Comment: I don't understand. If "congruence" means what I think it means then I don't know what you mean when you say that a subset of $A$ (as opposed to a subset of $A \times A$) is a congruence.

Answer (score 1):

Since you referred to the center of an *algebra* (rather than the center of a group), I believe you mean Definition 5.1 on page 35 of [the commutator book](http://math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Commutator/comm.pdf).  But by that definition it is obvious that the center is an equivalence relation.

So perhaps your confusion arises from talking about the center of a *group* rather than a general or "universal" algebra.  In that case, for a group $G$, the center $Z(G)$ is not really a congruence relation of $G$.  However, as a normal subgroup, $Z(G)$ is a single class of a congruence relation of $G$ -- namely, the class containing the identity element of $G$.

In general, each normal subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ can be identified with a congruence relation, $\theta_N$, of $G$.  The congruence classes of $\theta_N$ are the cosets of $N$.  Thus, the lattice of normal subgroups of $G$ is isomorphic to the lattice of congruence relations of $G$. It is because of this identification that a normal subgroup is sometimes loosely referred to as a "congruence" of the group.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151773/correspondence-for-universal-subalgebras-of-u-vartheta/161134#161134).